# Oscar fish turning pale

Tags: health

Hey so I have a tiger Oscar and it’s turned pale it’s only a couple months old and was completely fine until I started feed it blood worms 3 days ago they is a Barra in the tank with it but they are fine Oscar actually hangs out with the Barra so it’s not that I was thinking it might be because the tank is over stocked I am getting a new tank just waiting for it to come in to the store any help is appreciated

Comment: please post the readings of your latest water test PH-NITRITE-AMMONIA.is your tank properly cycled?,size of your tank any heating  or filtration in your tank?